# Is there any video footage of a full reentry?

Tags: space-shuttle, reentry, camera

Did any orbital craft ever fully film its reentry into the atmosphere, either as long as the camera worked or until the craft landed if it could? The Space Shuttles had a front camera that showed live the KSC / Edwards Air Force Base approach and landing from the orbiter itself, but they weren't filming when the shuttles entered the atmosphere, right? The live footage from the shuttle front camera were already from after the flight through the mesosphere. I'd appreciate if you could link me a video of an entering spacecraft from orbit. Thank you.

Comment: Why the shuttle tag when asking about any orbital craft?

Comment: Note that the shuttle dashcam was inside the spacecraft. It just looked out through one of the front windows.

Comment: @OrganicMarble That was Pearson's edit to make clear I don't mean a camera showing the astronauts but one that films out.

Comment: @lijat Because I wonder whether the shuttle's HUD camera was working outside the atmosphere. If it did, I'd like a footage of the entire reentry to be linked.

Comment: Per the shuttle Photo/TV Checklist page FS 2-24, the in-cabin camera and the HUD camera shared the same video cable. https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/567075main_P-TV_135_F_1.pdf  You got one or the other at the crew's discretion. I would guess they thought the HUD cam video was boring until landing.  The deleted answer is pretty good actually.

Comment: @OrganicMarble They didn't turn it on until they were in the lower stratosphere?

Comment: They switched from the cabin camera to the HUD camera whenever they felt like it.

Answer (score 1):

Not Earth, but probably one of the coolest atmospheric entry videos out there:

Comment: It’s not a full reentry

Answer (score 0):

I think SpaceX footage of reentering main booster are the only "full reentry videos" available as of now.

[image: SpaceX third stage reentry seen from onboard camera]